# XPath query how to get value of one attribute based on two attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to extract name attribute value from the following tag

```
<application
    comments="Do not erase this one"
    executable="run_CIET"
    icon="default"
    instances="1"
    mode="1"
    name="CIET"
    order="10"
    selection="1"
    tool="y"
/>
```

I can easily get value of name attribute value based on mode value as shown below

```
xpath Applications.xml '//applications/application[@mode='3']'/@name
```

But if I want to add more condtion which is "get name attribute value when mode=X and tool attribute is not there in application tag"

How do we do this? I tried something like

```
xpath Applications.xml '//applications/application[@mode='3' and !@tool]'/@name
```

but its not working.

I have not used XPath before and I am finding it tricky I search W3C help on XPath but did not find what I wanted. Please help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of your problem, a short and complete solution and some recommendations. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
How do we do this? I tried something like 

    xpath Applications.xml '//applications/application[@mode='3' and !@tool]'/@name

but its not working.



!@tool
```

is invalid syntax in XPath. There is an `!=` operator, but no `!` operator.

**Use**:

```
//applications/application[@mode='3' and not(@tool)]/@name
```

There are two things you should always try to avoid:

1. using the `!=` operator -- it has weird definition and doesn't behave like the `not()` function --never use it if one of the operands is a node-set.
2. Try to avoid as much as possible using the `//` abbreviation -- this may cause signifficant inefficiency and also has anomalous behavior that isn't apperent to most people.

Answer (score 6):

Using `not(@tool)` instead of `!@tool` should do the job. If your XPath engine's not behaving you could conceivably do `count(@tool)=0`, but that shouldn't be necessary.